# Invoke value on range input

Tags: dom-events, cypress, invoke

I am trying to change a value on a native html5 range input with Cypress. Here is the code:

```
cy.get('input[type="range"]')
.invoke('val', 5)
.trigger('change')
```

I get an error that says:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.invoke() errored because the property: 'val' does not exist on your subject.
>
> cy.invoke() waited for the specified property 'val' to exist, but it never did.

I have confirmed the input does exist in the assertion. I have also confirmed it is selecting the proper element (range input.)

Any ideas on what the issue is and why this doesn't work? Cypress documentation indicates this would work for me as shown in their examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the console, there is no `val()` on this input type (don't know why), but the `.value` property is available for getting and setting,
so

```js
cy.get('input[type="range"]')
  .then($input => $input[0].value = 5);
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/eYNNMmv?editors=1111) for experimenting.

```js
<input type="range" min="5" max="10" step="0.01">

//console.log(document.querySelector('input').val())

console.log(document.querySelector('input').value)   // "7.5"

document.querySelector('input').value = 9

console.log(document.querySelector('input').value)   // "9"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry about my delayed response. The problem in my case is that I am using React & MobX (state management.) I need to invoke change on the input itself using native browser events so that the change propagates through React and ultimately gets updated in the MobX store. In your example above you are changing the property directly in the DOM; however, that change never fires off the event listeners to update the state of the application.

Comment: Adding `cy.wrap($input).trigger('change')` may send the required event.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks Richard.